# Can the headers of an AjaxFallbackDefaultDataTable be updated via AJAX?

Tags: java, ajax, wicket, wicket-1.5

I'm currently writing a web application. I am using an `AjaxFallbackDefaultDataTable` to display domain objects. The tables include pagination and so far everything works just fine.

What I want to be able to do:
In my implementation of `IColumn<T>` I am returning my own header component via  `Component getHeader(String componentId)`. This component depends on the page and page size which is currently used by the table (it shows a link to another page which should only care about the current slice of data). Now, I have implemented the `void onPageChanged()` method of the table so that it updates the columns accordingly.

**Problem:**
I am using the Wicket AJAX debug window and it shows me that the whole table is rerendered on the server and sent to the client. However, the headers doesn't seem to update correctly so that I'm forever stuck with page 0. Using a debugger I can clearly see that `Component getHeader(String componentId)` is only called once, when the table is created initially.

**Question:**
Is there any way I can solve this issue without writing my own implementation of an AJAXified data table? If not, can somebody please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HeadersToolbar creates the headers once only.

Either you implement your own toolbar recreating the headers before each render, or rewrite your header component to always render an up-to-date link.

Comment: Yep, updating the component itself was the key to success. Thanks to the new event system in Wicket 1.5, implementing this in a decoupled way was a piece of cake!